# can I return an alert for quantities over minimum stock?

Tags: netsuite

Can someone please help me with the following code.  I am having problems with the value from custitem10 this is a stored integer number on the item however my formula does not seem to pull the number through.  I have tested this by just putting in random number and code seemed to work fine, any suggestions?

```
function fieldChanged(type, name)
{
    if (name == 'quantity')
    {

        if (nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','quantity') >= nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custitem10'))
        {
            alert("Order is above the minimum stock held. Please contact purchasing once you have completed the invoice.");
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (name == 'custbody533')
    {
        if (lodalert == "T")
        {
        alert("Letter of demand has been sent to this customer\n\nCustomer must pay for goods upfront!");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the 'custitem' value in the item record. Use the nlapiLookupField API to retrieve the record's field value.

```
if (name == 'quantity')
{
        var itemId = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','itemId');
        var itemCustomVal = nlapiLookupField('item', itemId, 'custitem10');

    if (nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','quantity') >= itemCustomVal)
    {
        alert("Order is above the minimum stock held. Please contact purchasing once you have completed the invoice.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct in that you will need to lookup the value from the item record. You may also need to ensure that NetSuite gives you both values as Numbers instead of Strings: `parseInt(nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity') >= parseInt(itemCustomVal)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using nlapiLookupField for each line item. I would suggest that you create a custom column field on the SO that sources the item custom field.

nlapiLookupField consumes usage count, so if your SO has a lot of line items, you might run into usage limits for client side scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Do parseInt or paraeFloat before the comparison. You are comparing 2 strings there...

Also wouldn't it be better to just do a scheduled report with an email alert for minimum stock?

Comment: This Script is to be used by the Sales reps as they are creating invoices in order to warn them that stock may not be available.  This will let them warn customers that goods may not leave on the day.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help have come up with the code below which seems to be working.  Its a bit of a frankenstein of all your answers and im sure there is a much better way to code this but i am certainly no developer and this works for me.   Again thanks for the help!

```
function fieldChanged(type, name)
{   
    var lodalert = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody533');
    var paymentby = nlapiGetFieldText('custbody14');



    if (name == 'quantity')
    {   
                var itemId = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item');
                var itemMinStock = nlapiLookupField("item", itemId, "custitem10");
                var itemq = parseInt(nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity'));
                if (itemq < 1)
        {
            alert("Quantity is less than 1. You might want to use the 'Broken Price' Price level");
            return true;
        }
        if (itemq >= itemMinStock)
        {
            alert("Order is above the minimum stock held. Please contact purchasing once you have completed the invoice.");
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (name == 'custbody533')
    {
        if (lodalert == "T")
        {
        alert("Letter of demand has been sent to this customer\n\nCustomer must pay for goods upfront!");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```